# No thread bound Request in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, microservices, completable-future

I am new to Spring boot.

I have two microServices(MS) running.

From 1st MS, I have a code like below

List models.
and for each of the entries of the models, I am invoking a call to 2nd MS like below

`models.stream().filter(mod -> isModActive(<Call to 2nd MS>)).collect(Collectors.toList())` --- (Invoker)

The above code snippet takes a time of 30 secs.

Now, I want to optimize the code.
For this, I divided the models into batches of 20.
For Each batch, I am invoking the code like below

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> batch1.stream().filter(mod -> isModActive(<Call to 2nd MS>)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

After invoking the batches using CompletableFuture, I am combining their results in code.

During execution, I am getting an exception - No thread bound request for Dispatcher Servelet. Use RequestContextListener instead.

I checked this error and tried using all the scenarios which were mentioned like - making a bean method to return RequestContextListnere, using @Async and making a custom threadpoolExecutor in the main Application class, nothing helped.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Already mentioned in the description.

Comment: Can you please add to your question the StackTrace of the error (one of them at least)

Comment: Hi @JorgeCampos
Unfortunately, I cannot paste the stack trace here. But the error is exactly same as that of https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-request-scope-error-no-thread-bound-request-found/

Comment: Also, if only a single call were to be made asynchronously to different ms, I am able to achieve that using a bean method which return RequentCOntextListener. My problem is coming because I a stream of data and I am unable to figure out how to do that for the stream.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the exact error you have. As it currently stands, there is not enough information to provide an accurate answer.